# add extra divs to the dom jquery ( toogle click more function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my first post in this website and I just wonder if someone can help me with a problem that has been going on for a week now, I dont know much on javascript, but I'll try to explain the problem as much as I can.

> For example when you press ''more'' in column 1 and 2 you will see a
>   gap under the columns on the right side.Those are the gaps I need
>   to fill with extra divs.
>
> It would be great to fill the gaps with extras divs (separately from
>   the columns like a quote or image but ofcourse with the same function), now I looked at >tutorials based on
>   "adding element to DOM jquery" but I just didnt get it :(  read it and
>   read it and still dont understand it. here are the columns with the
>   function and you'll see the gaps once you press `"More"`
>
> the images show the extra hidden div appearing at the same time next
>   to the column extended that fills the gap to make the other column
>   that hasnt been extended even

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/angie333/2YAxe/1/)

[picture of the gaps](http://oi59.tinypic.com/14kazw2.jpg)

click_toggle.js

```
clickMenu = function(menu,element,cname) {
    var getEls = document.getElementById(menu).getElementsByTagName(element);

    for (var i=0; i<getEls.length; i++) {
            getEls[i].onclick=function() {
            if ((this.className.indexOf(cname))!=-1)
            {
            if ((this.className.indexOf('click'))!=-1) {
                this.className=this.className.replace("click", "");;
                }
                else {
                this.className+=" click";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

more.css:

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
/* Float classes */
.f_right { float: right; }
.f_left { float: left; }



/* always visible */
#outer .holder {padding:1em; border:1px solid #ddd; margin:0 20px 10px 0;}
#outer .holder p {padding:5px 0 0 0; margin:0;}
#outer .holder p.bold {font-weight:bold;}
#outer .holder h2 {margin:0; padding:0;}

/* unclicked style div.more */
#outer div.more i {float:right; margin-right:-10px 10px 0 0; cursor:pointer; color:#c00; font-weight:bold;}
#outer div.more i.hide {display:none;}
#outer div.more p {display:none;}
#outer div.more img {display:none;}

/* clicked style div.click */
#outer div.click i.show {display:none;}
#outer div.click i.hide {display:block;}
#outer div.click p {display:block;}
#outer div.click img {display:block; float:left; padding-right:10px;}
```

Comment: If the system tells you that you can't include a link to jsfiddle without including code, you should probably include some code.

Comment: is it ok now? Didnt know what to put, it wouldnt let me press the code option.

Comment: There is no **code** in your question.  `"More"` is not code.  Based on your tags, your question is about `html`, `css` and `javascript`.  Perhaps add some of that in there?  You have a jsfiddle, so presumably some of the code from there is relevant to the question?

Comment: is it ok now? js fiddle is there on the question, ill put it again here: http://jsfiddle.net/angie333/2YAxe/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your markup / code is a bit hard to follow. Here's how I'd go about it:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2gZU/2/)

I've used JQuery to make the code a bit easier to work with and used some simpler markup to clarify the example. Note that because I've used the parent/find methods in JQuery, and given everything classes, it's easy to have more than one box and each will work independently.

You can put whatever content you want to be shown and hidden inside the "extraContent" divs - in my example I've put some headers, paragraphs and an image but this can be anything.

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

$(".toggleLink").on("click", function() {
    // $(this) will be the "more" / "less" link that was clicked.
    // Find its parent, then inside that - select the "extra content"
    // box and toggle its visibility
    var extraContentBox = $(this).parent().find(".extraContent");
    extraContentBox.toggle();

    // Update the text of the toggle link based on the new visiblility
    // of the "extra content" div
    var linkText = (extraContentBox.is(':visible')) ? "less" : "more";
    $(this).parent().find(".toggleLink").text(linkText);
});

});
```

**UPDATE:**

I think you'll need to experiment to get it to look right. Here are a few basic things you might need:

To hide an element initially add "display: none;" to the CSS, or in a style tag like this:

```
<div style="display: none;"></div>
```

To select an element with JQuery, use `#id` or `.class`, e.g.:

```
$("#someElementID").show();
$(".someClass").hide();
```

Use an ID to give a specific element a name (must be unique on the page). Use classes for things that are used more than once.

To do something when an element is clicked:

```
$("#someElement").on("click", function() {
    // code here
});
```

To determine if an element is visible:

```
var isVisible = $("#someElement").is(":visible");
if (isVisible) { 
    // do something
}
```

To get the height of an element:

```
var height = $("#someElement").height();
```

To set the height of an element:

```
$("#someElement").height(100);
```

Comment: hope it will come out, i have one last question , how do i block a div from moving when the page expands because of this function?

Comment: The content will move around to fit the expanded elements - this is natural because of the way the elements are positioned (generally, things are stacked below other elements, or to the side of them etc). There's "position: absolute;" to take elements out of the natural "flow" and have them appear at specific positions, but then you might end up obscuring other content. Look up CSS positioning for more info. Alternatively, if want to allow elements to move around on the page, but still want to ensure that something is visible you can scroll the page with http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I presume you mean that you want to match the height of the boxes so that they line up next to each other? You could use Javascript to update the height of the containing divs after the new content is shown.

Inside your click handler, after you show/hide the extra content, you could (for each row) fetch the height of each box, and update the others to match the height of the tallest one.

If you're using JQuery, have a look at https://api.jquery.com/height/ - you can use this to both get the height of an element or set it.

In my browser at least, it looks like you have rows with two columns in each - rather than four columns. If this is the case, you'd need to do some logic to loop over the rows and work on pairs of boxes.

Comment: no I mean add extra divs to cover the gaps when a column expands (hidden content appears) due to ''more'' function.For example when you press ''more'' in column 1 and 2 you will see a gap underneath the columns on the right side.Those are the gaps I need to fill with extra divs.

Comment: Why do you need to add extra divs? Will they have any content or do you just mean create empty divs to correct the padding / alignment? If thats the case, it seems better to just resize the divs you already have.

Comment: add hidden extra divs under the columns that would appear at the same time as the hidden text and column expanding when ''more'' is pressed ( I would add a text quote and another div would have an image ) to fill the gaps, should i put an image for a better idea?

Comment: I just dont know how add extra hidden divs within the click toogle.js function and in the css :( please help

Comment: Struggling to understand what you mean - but I've done another answer which might help.

Comment: I'm so sorry I didnt explain well, here are two examples, I hope it helps I truly appreciate you helping me with this, thank you so much , example one : http://oi57.tinypic.com/9plxc6.jpg       example two:http://oi59.tinypic.com/14kazw2.jpg

Comment: the images show the extra hidden div appearing at the same time next to the column extended that fills the gap to make the other column that hasnt been extended even

Comment: If your content is fixed, you could give specific elements (e.g. the wine bottle, or a div containing a quote) IDs and show/hide them in code based on which panels are expanded. See my other answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21535952/1145963) for an example click handler, it shows how you can react to the clicks, and how to test the visibility of an element. But if the content is dynamic, it would be very hard to determine where the gaps will be and how much space you have to play with, so I don't know how that would work.

Comment: is it possible to just to add a general hidden div with the same toogle.js function click "more" from the columns that extend to fill the gap on the opposite direction and separately through  html instead of css to change the size of each div separately? I dont know how to implement this hidden div within the toogle function and on the html.

Comment: in this code i published on the question where can i put within the script the parent and child adding the extra hidden div?