# How to replace one js function for another on columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Change of plans, can someone please advice me on adding a function with hidden divs for each column that blends one to another when a user presses the button?**

I used a function but at the end it only caused more gaps and more complications making the page and its other elements a mess, then I found another function in a jsfiddle that
 would be great to use instead and it seems to be much simpler.

Can someone please help me replace the current function for the other function for the columns?

```
**This function would be ideal to replace the current function, giving the slide
 effect with hidden column extra divs (a,b,c) all on one column 
(marked as Column1) for example** 

**Instead of the current function that expands the column by pressing "more", 
 replace it by having all on one column just like a picture 
slideshow ----> the column has (divbox) slides with different content on it**
```

**Ideal function for each column**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ptkw/117/)

**Current Function with the 4 columns**

> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXSu5/5/)

**Please I beg you I really need help, I would deeply appreciate it.Please, I know there are talented people here who can do this in a minute, I wish I knew this but no matter how I try and trust me I really tried , can't learn it, it doesn't go through :(
Please

Comment: [Welcome to SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Can you please provide the actual code and explain more clearly what parts of the code causes you problems.

Comment: I already asked in another question posted yesterday and there was no improvements and the gaps stayed the same, I dont know javascript, so I would appreciate if the new function can actually replace the one that is currently with the columns,but dont know how to do it, tried and the results were very bad, messy .

Comment: this was the question I mentioned before the reason why its better the function gets replace for the new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534683/add-extra-divs-to-the-dom-jquery-toogle-click-more-function

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Valtos/ZXSu5/4/ ????

Comment: I just need the current function to be replaced with the new one as it's explained on the question.

Comment: You need an accordion then?

Comment: dont know what accordion means, I just need this function to work on the columns instead of the one I have now, like replace ''read more'' (expanding column by click function) for this one instead that gives 3 slides transition (hidden divs) for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angie, I hope this is what you are looking for.

[Modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/6Ptkw/119/)

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('div[name|=box]').each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
            $(this).slideDown(200);
        } else {
            $(this).slideUp(600);
        }
    });
}
```

Just basically placed your articles in the slides.  You will have to adjust the img urls and work on CSS styling.

Hope that works out for you.

Comment: Are you looking for 4 columns all side by side but they are hidden until you click a button?

Comment: @AngieLee, The original function actually works by manipulating the class names and using CSS to hide the second page.  It's a mess and a bad practice.  It would be better to write new code from scratch.  I'm sure you could find a programmer near by who could do the job for you.  Stackoverflow really only for solving specific problems.  Good luck.